# How to uncomment the a specific line which contains specific text in a hocon file using bash script(sed,awk..etc)

Tags: sed

I have a hocon file Having the following text in it in which I want to uncomment the line which has the CPU in it

```
   // Size of buffer for events waiting to be processed by the fetcher. Typically, this should       
    // be at least 3-4x  number of cores to ensure that the processing pipeline is making use of       
    // all available CPUs and it is always running       maxFetcherBufferSize: 100
```

Comment: Do you want to uncomment the text "all available CPUs....", or do you want to generate an uncommented line with the text "maxFetcherBufferSize: 100"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do like this

```
sed -r '/CPU/{s/[^//]*\/\/\b*(.*)/\1/}' filename
```

> If you want to edit file in place, use **-i** option.